# ¿Cómo solucionar la excepción javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: elemento inesperado al convertir string xml a objetos?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xml-schema

Tengo el siguiente método para convertir un string xml a objetos y cuando lo mando a llamar y lo ejecuto manda la siguiente excepcion:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: elemento inesperado (URI:"http://www.prueba/cadena/ejemplo/1.00", local:"OU_SchemaPublic"). Los elementos esperados son <{http://www.prueba/cadena/ejemplo/1.00}SchemaPublic>
```

```html
@Override
    public DatosInputDto  convertXmlToDatosInputDto (String xml) {
        DatosInputDto  input = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DatosInputDto.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            input = (DatosInputDto) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return input;
    }
```

este es el string con el xml que recibo

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nd0:OU_SchemaPublic xmlns:nd0="http://www.prueba/cadena/ejemplo/1.00">
    <nd0:TTT_Code>LIM28</nd0:TTT_Code>
    <nd0:TTT_Date>20210622</nd0:TTT_Date>
    <nd0:TTT_CodeType>0203</nd0:TTT_CodeType>
    <nd0:TTT_Receiver>0098</nd0:TTT_Receiver>
    <nd0:TTT_SenderPT>0092</nd0:TTT_SenderPT>
    <nd0:TTT_DocumentFile>Documents</nd0:TTT_DocumentFile>
</nd0:OU_SchemaPublic>
```

Y esta es mi clase donde mapeo esos datos que me llegan en el xml

```html
@XmlRootElement(name = "datosInputDto ")
public class DatosInputDto implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4596758570871609534L;

    private String code;
    private String date;
    private String codeType;
    private String receiver
    private String senderPt;
    private String documentFile;

}
```

y tengo la clase llamada package.info con lo siguiente:

```html
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "nd0",
            namespaceURI = "http://www.prueba/cadena/ejemplo/1.00")},
        namespace = "http://www.prueba/cadena/ejemplo/1.00",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.prueba;
```

¿Qué me esta faltando o en qué estoy mal?
por que lanza esa excepción y como puedo resolverla

Comment: Cuando trabajes con XML, JSON u otros, revisa los elementos cuando el código falle, de lo contrario podrías pasar una eternidad intentando hacer funcionar el código cuando el problema está en el elemento en sí y el código no funcionará mientras el elemento no sea válido, que es lo que ocurre aquí precisamente: **el XML no es válido**. En [este enlace tienes un validador en línea](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-validator). Si pegas el XML allí verás que a la izquierda te pone los errores o advertencias. En tu caso, el nodo debe cerrar así: `</nd0:OU_SchemaPublic>` porque así empieza.

Comment: si, fue mi error al copiarlo, pero en si  en el String me llega correcto

Comment: Es extraño que la anotación `@XmlRootElement` tenga `name="datosInputDto"`, siendo que ahí debería referirse al elemento raíz en el XML, `OU_SchemaPublic`. ¿no?

Comment: ya lo modifique a como dices y ya no me manda error,gracias.  pero le hago un get a cualquiera de los campos y vienen null, se supone ya debo de ver el valor que traen en el xml  no?